# Is there anyway to limit GPU usage/load (%) of a specific application?

Tags: laptop, gpu, cooling, speed, temperature

I'm using an application that always uses 100% of GPU. This makes my laptop heat up, and also makes it difficult to do other GPU-related tasks while the application is running.

I would like to limit the GPU load something like 60%, to relieve the stress on the GPU and the fans on my laptop.

I know that for CPU, there's a way to prioritize processes. But this just makes it so that the particular application consumes what's not used by other applications... the total CPU usage would still be 100%. Also, I don't think this suggestion can be applied to GPUs.

I don't want to open my laptop to apply new thermal paste, and I am already using a cooling pad. I'm hoping there's a software solution. I'm already on the lowest battery-saver mode.